# Calculate average conditionally based on an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a requirement where I need to calculate the average of units sold for a product based on the company they were sold at. From there I will calculate the percentage difference to unit sold. There is one model with products in it. Each product has the attributes of:

- product_name
- unit_sold
- company

There are many companies.

This code works for calculating the average on all records, however I'd like to calculate the average conditionally based on the attribute 'company'.

```
def average_UnitSold
    self.class.average(:unit_sold)
  end

def averagechange_UnitSold
      (self.unit_sold - average_UnitSold) / average_UnitSold * 100
  end
```

I came up with this, but it is not working:

```
def average_UnitSold
      self.class.sum(:unit_sold), :conditions => "company = self.company")) / :unit_sold
    end
```

Any ideas?

On another note, is a more viable approach storing all these averages somewhere and only updating them on a daily basis more efficient?

Based on the answer, I have now implemented this code, and it seems to work:

```
 def self.average_unit_sold(company)
   where(company: company).average(:unit_sold)
 end

 def average_unit_sold
          self.class.average_unit_sold(self.company)
        end

 def averagechange_UnitSold
      (self.unit_sold - average_unit_sold) / average_unit_sold * 100
  end
```

Comment: Do you have any associations between your models? That would make things surprisingly simple.

Comment: Hey there is just the one model for this

Comment: no `Company` model? That's odd. Data structure suggests it. @infused showed what I mean in his answer.

Comment: Yeah the data isn't created in the application, it is purely read only from an external source, so it's just flat. Thanks for your input though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very strange that you're doing this in an instance method, since the result doesn't actually have anything to do with a particular instance. Instead, define a class method:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # `self.average_unit_sold` is a class method that takes `company` as an
  # argument and executes an SQL query like this (where 'some_company' is the
  # company given in the argument):
  #
  #     SELECT AVG(products.unit_sold) FROM products
  #       WHERE products.company = 'some_company'
  #
  def self.average_unit_sold(company)
    where(company: company).average(:unit_sold)
  end
end

# ...then...
Product.average_unit_sold(some_company)
```

If you *really* want to have an instance method, you can add one (but keep the logic in a class method):

```
# `average_unit_sold` is an instance method that takes the value of the 
# instance's own `company` attribute and calls `Product.average_unit_sold`:
def average_unit_sold
  self.class.average_unit_sold(self.company)
end
```

(This could also be a `scope`, but for aesthetic reasons I prefer to use scopes only when the result is a model instance or collection of instances, which isn't the case here.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have added in the code above and it seems to work.. Could you help explaining why? I am new to ruby

Comment: @bnussey It's pretty basic, and I don't think I could explain it better than the Rails documentation can. Read [Active Record Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) for an overview of how Rails models work, and then [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) to understand how database queries in Rails work. Eventually you'll want to read all of the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), probably sooner rather than later.

Comment: Awesome thanks for that, and for adding the further explanation in the answer.

Comment: Hey @Jordan how would you go about using this in a scope? My current code is: scope :upward_trending, -> { where( "unit_sold > ?", average(:unit_sold)) } .. how do I reference the company here?

Comment: You would give the block an argument: `scope :upward_trending, ->(company) { … }`. Then you can use `company` inside the block and call the scope just like you did class method.

Comment: Hey @Jordan thanks for all your help. I came up with this:

`scope :upward_trending, ->(company) {where( "unit_sold > ?", where(company: company).average(:unit_sold)) }`


But am getting an argument 0 for 1 error

Comment: How are you calling it? You should be calling it like `Product.upward_trending(some_company)`.

Comment: Hey @Jordan quick question for you. We're importing this data from an external source, so to gain better performance, I am going to do this calculation on import. Any ideas how I would calculate the average from a different model -- an import task? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @bnussey You should probably ask that as a new question, with as much detail as you can provide.

Comment: Hey @Jordan have asked the question here - (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733786/calculate-average-conditionally-based-on-an-attribute-in-a-rake-task-rails) - would be great if you could assist, thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your associations set up correctly this is pretty easy to accomplish. So assuming that a Company has many products:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Average units sold for all companies:

```
Product.average(:unit_sold)
```

Average units sold for one company:

```
company = Company.find(1)
company.products.average(:unit_sold)
```

Comment: Hey @infused the data is not created in the application, but comes from an external source, so these associations have not been set up. What is the advantage in doing this?