# Calculate average conditionally based on an attribute in a rake task (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a requirement where I need to calculate the average of units sold for a product based on the company they were sold at.

The scenario is we're importing data from a legacy database, and when importing I'd like to perform some calculations based on the difference between units sold for new item and the average of the existing item's, when they were sold at the same company.

The model is called Product and has attributes of:

- name
- interest (How many units were sold)
- company (What company they
  were sold at)

Now previously, I am able to calculate the average of each company on the model like so:

```
def self.average_interest(company)
        where(company: company).average(:interest)
    end
```

But now I am trying to do the calculation on a rake task.

Here's what I came up with and it's not working:

```
@company = u.Company
#u.Company is the field name from the legacy database

        def average_interest
            Product.average(:interest, :conditions => ['company = ?', @company]) 
        end
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Have updated it from '@company' to @company however the value being returned is still incorrect

Comment: Hey @Jordan have posted the question here, would be great if you can assist

Comment: You're passing `@category` as `'@category'` -- which is a string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after playing around, looks like it was only a slight adjustment from the original code that was needed.

Just had to add the model (Product) to the query in the code:

```
def average_interest(company)
    Product.where(company: company).average(:interest)
end
```

And then I am storing it in a variable like so:

```
 @company_average = average_interest(u.Company)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your rake task you can pass in the variable, so something like this:

```
def average_interest(company)
  Product.average(:interest, :conditions => ['company = ?', company]) 
end

unentered_legacy_companies.each do |u|
    average_interest(u)
end
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply. Whoops, was trying a few things and forgot to change it back. Nevertheless it still returns an incorrect value :(

Comment: @bnussey Another thing, instance variables (e.g. '@company') are typically only used in the controller, not in a rake task. If you are doing this in a rake task you can make the method look as before, see my updated answer above. When you say the value being returned is incorrect what do you mean?

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your reply. Looks like it's still not working. so it's returning a value of 63.1642768431749 when the average is actually around 452, so it's really bizarre. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey I got it working, please see code in my answer :) Thanks for your help!!